# Is there a way to mix markdown and code in a single cell in Jupyter Notebook? Or import code/markdown into eachothers cells?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets

I would like to create a table which explains different cases for electrical phenomena in separate columns. Therefore, I'd like to have a description for each case in the first row, some LaTeX formulas in the second row, some animated diagrams in the third row, further LaTeX formulas, more diagrams etc. The last row should have a single cell, which spans all three columns, and contains an interactive animation where the students can choose from the explained cases and play around with parameters. However, I do not know how to get it all together without leaving the markdown or Python environment.

Alternatively, is there some widget which can contain markdown/LaTeX?

Kind regards,

-Domme